# How do I set Content-type using Bubblewrap HTTP?

Tags: ios, ruby, http-headers, rubymotion

I'm trying to post a request with content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. But when I view the request with Charles (or Fiddler) it says application/json.

```
        HTTP.post(url, 
            {
                :headers => {"Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
            }) do |response| 
            puts response
            puts response.body.to_str
        end
```

Comment: Your example works fine for me, Charles shows "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in the Request tab. Is the specific example you posted giving you problems, or did you try to simplify it for this post? If so, please post more details on what you're actually passing into HTTP.post

Comment: It is simplified, the url is really something like "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=#{code}&client_id=#{CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=#{CLIENT_SECRET}&redirect_uri=#{REDIRECT_URI}&grant_type=authorization_code". The same url works when I try to post 'unwrapped' with NSMutableURLRequest and NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest

Comment: Any you're sure you're looking at the "Request" tab in Charles, not the "Overview" tab (which will show a JSON type because that's what Google responds with). If you're willing, could you post an issue to https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap/issues?sort=comments&state=open with as much detail as possible so we can look into it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
BW::HTTP.post("http://foo.bar.com/", {payload: data, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} }) do |response|
```